# Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have registration form and button. OnClick - I call function on server side which make a validation of user's zip code at Database with Zipcodes. If validation passed successfully - user's data stored in Database (here I continue use server function). But if ZipCode does not match - I call Javascript function where I ask if user still wants to save his data to DB. and If yes - I save it using Ajax request. Problem is when I call Javascript function  - firstly it should receive user's data on client side. But when reading data happens - I receive an error "Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference". But user's data still exist at the form's fields. It seems that the data that read by the server from the form once - reset somewhere - and can not be read a second time on the client. 
Here is my ASP Form

```
<body>
  <form id="frmZipValidation" runat="server">
     <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server">Registration Form</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbxName"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbxZipCode"></asp:TextBox>            
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLCountry">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select country" Value="Select" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="USA" Value="USA"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Canada" Value="Canada"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbxState"></asp:TextBox> 
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbxCity"></asp:TextBox> 
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Here is my Server Side

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string Name;
    string ZipCode;
    string Country;
    string State;
    string City;
    bool IsMatch;
    Addresses dbAddresses = new Addresses();
    User newUser;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["Action"] != null && Request["Action"].Trim() != "")
        {
            if (Request["Action"] == "AddUser")
            {
                AddUser(Request["Name"], Request["ZipCode"], Request["Country"], Request["State"], Request["City"]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddUser(string UserName, string UserZip, string UserCountry, string UserState, string UserCity)
    {
        newUser = new User(UserName, UserZip, UserCountry, UserState, UserCity);
        dbAddresses.Users.Add(newUser);
        dbAddresses.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            ZipCode = txtbxZipCode.Text;
            Country = DDLCountry.Text;
            State = txtbxState.Text;
            City = txtbxCity.Text;
            Name = txtbxName.Text;
            IsMatch = false;

            List<ZipCode> ZipC = (from z in dbAddresses.Zips
                                  where z.Zip == ZipCode
                                  select z).ToList();

            //If ZipCode entered by client do not exists at Database return false
            if (!ZipC.Any())
            {
                IsMatch = false;
            }
            else
            {                    
                for (int i = 0; i < ZipC.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (ZipC[i].Country.ToString() == Country)
                    {
                        if (ZipC[i].State.ToString() == State)
                        {
                            if (ZipC[i].City.ToString() == City)
                            {
                                AddUser(Name, ZipCode, Country, State, City);

                                //Message to the user that all saved successfully
                                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "1", "<script>alert('Your data was saved successfully!');</script>");
                                IsMatch = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                IsMatch = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            IsMatch = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IsMatch = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //If user's data are not match, then go to JS client code where - If user wants in any case to save data - make it using AJAX request 
            if (!IsMatch)
            {
                string clientScript = "AjaxRequestSaveToDB();";
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyClientScript", clientScript);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is Javascript:

```
function AjaxRequestSaveToDB()
{
var SaveData = confirm('Zip/Postal code doesn’t match region. Are you sure you want to save this data?');

if (SaveData)
   {
    var UserName = document.getElementById('txtbxName').value;
    var UserZipCode = document.getElementById('txtbxZipCode').value;
    var UserCountry = document.getElementById('DDLCountry').value;
    var USerState = document.getElementById('txtbxState').value;
    var UserCity = document.getElementById('txtbxCity').value;
    SendDataToServer('AddUser', UserName, UserZipCode, UserCountry, USerState, UserCity);
    alert("You data was saved successfully!");
    }
else { alert('Not saved');
    }
   }
}

function SendDataToServer(RequestType, Name, ZipCode, Country, State, City)
{
    var xmlHttp = getXmlHttp();

    var Url = "Default.aspx?Action=" + escape(RequestType)
    + "&Name=" + escape(Name)
    + "&ZipCode=" + escape(ZipCode)
    + "&Country=" + escape(Country)
    + "&State=" + escape(State)
    + "&City=" + escape(City);

    xmlHttp.open("GET", Url, true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

Comment: what if instead of seeing that the zipcode is empty at the server, you use a html button and perform the check on the client side as soon as the button is clicked and then trigger a postback from there if needed? The issue I think is that the ASP button is doing a full page post back and refresh so when you call the javascript function after the post back all the values that were entered by the user are gone as far as the page is concerned.

Comment: I tried from the beginning to get all the data on the client side, and then transfer them to the server for validation of the database, but then when I need to switch back to the client - the program does not make the transition. It just does not recognize the code of call to javascript function. I write it as:   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "1", "<script>AjaxRequestSaveToDB();</script>"); I even tried with simple "alert" - does not work...

Comment: unfortunately I think your best bet to make the page do what you want and also for the most streamlined user experience will be almost a complete rewrite, using client side controls(possibly with jquery validation), an AJAX request with XML content and an asp.net handler page. When I get a free minute I will write out a complete answer for you. In the meantime [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp) goes over custom ajax requests fairly thoroughly.

Comment: Mike, Thank you for advice. I will appreciate if you will help me a little with a code as I am a beginner in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short book about Client-Server Communications using "Custom" AJAX requests.

In ASP.net programming (almost) every time the client interacts with the server, the client sends all of its information to the server and then throws out its old content and replaces it with the response the client received from the server. So the problem you were running into is that your `asp:button` on the client machine was sending information to your `.aspx` page on the server and the server was interpreting the information, realizing something was wrong and telling the client it should ask the user for more information but throw out all the information that had been previously entered.

The best way that I have found to get around this problem is to use what I call "custom AJAX requests." Basically this means that we write a string of XML and send it to an ASP handler page which is set up to accept the XML string and do something with it. In my travels I have slimmed this down to basically 3 parts. The first is the user interface which contains all of the markup and CSS(and validation), the second is the JavaScript file that contains all of the data gathering and the actual AJAX request and lastly there is the `ashx` file that handles the request from the client.

So to start you will need to set up your user interface. Something along the lines of:

```
<body>
  <form id="frmZipValidation" runat="server">
     <div>
        <div class="label">Registration Form<div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxName" class="txtbxName" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxZipCode" class="txtbxZipCode" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>            
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCountry" class="DDLCountry" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select country" Value="Select" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="USA" Value="USA"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Canada" Value="Canada"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxState" class="txtbxState" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxCity" class="txtbxCity" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox> 
        <input id="btnSubmit" class="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Save" onclick="SubmitForm()" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Couple things to note with this:

1. The button to submit the form is NOT an ASP button but a HTML button.
2. All of the input controls are ASP controls but they have the `ClientIDMode` set to `Static`, this will only work in .NET 4.0 or higher.
3. We set the `class` to the same thing as the `ID` in case we aren't using .NET 4.0 or higher. Any CSS classes that you want to also add to the control can be added after the dummy ID class.(for my examples I'm assuming you are in .NET 4.0 but I can easily switch them to work without the `ClientIDMode` attribute if you need)

The second piece to the puzzle is the JavaScript. There are a couple ways that we can accomplish what we need. The first is by using vanilla JS without the help of any plugins or external libraries. This saves a very small amount of processing time, a marginal amount of loading time and can accomplish everything we ask of it. But, if we include an external library, JQuery, and plugin, JQuery Validation, then we can make our lives a whole heck of a lot easier during the programming phase by reducing the amount of code we have to write by a factor of about 10. And if we are really concerned about the load times then we can use the client cache to store the external libraries so that they only have to download them once. So whether or not you decide to use any external JavaScript libraries is up to what your project needs but since you are only concerned with validating that the zip code is not empty I will not use any JQuery but I just thought it would be worth mentioning because of how streamlined it makes the process.

Once you are ready to submit your form your first step will be to validate that the zipcode is valid. You can do this a couple ways depending on how in depth you want to get. The quickest check would just be to verify that the zip code text box is not empty when the button is clicked. So to do that we would just need to do:

```
function SubmitForm() { //This will be assigned as the click handler on your button in your HTML
    if (document.getElementById('txtbxZipCode').value != null && document.getElementById('txtbxZipCode').value != '') {
        Save('YourHandler', GetQueryString, GetXmlString, SuccessHandler, FailureHandler);
    } else {
        //Your user needs to know what went wrong...
    }
}
```

So, down to the meat and potatoes of this whole situation. The AJAX request. I've come up with a reusable function that handles the entire AJAX request that looks like:

```
function Save(handlerName, GetQueryString, GetXmlString, SuccessHandler, FailureHandler) {
    // Date.GetTime gets the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970, so we divide by 1000 to get the seconds. 
    end = (new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 30;
    //This variable is the actual AJAX request. This object works for IE8+ but if you want backwards compatability for earlier versions you will need a different object which I can dig up for you if you need.
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //This is the function that fires everytime the status of the request changes. 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //Get all the headers to determine whether or not the request was successful. This is a header you will need to add to the response manually.
            var xx = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Success");
            //the object xx will be a string that you designate. I chose to use True as the indicator that it was successful because it was intuitive.
            var x1 = xx.trim();
            if (x1 != undefined && x1 == 'True' && (new Date().getTime() / 1000) < end) {
                //If the response was successful and the timeout hasn't elapsed then we get the XML from the response and call the success handler
                var xmlResponse = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                SuccessHandler(sender, xmlResponse);
            } else if ((new Date().getTime() / 1000) < end) {
                //If the response was not successful and the timeout hasn't elapsed then we get the XML from the response and call the failure handler
                var xmlResponse = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                FailureHandler(sender, xmlResponse);
            } //If the request was successful
        } //If the readystate is 4 and the status is 200
    }  //OnReadyStateChanged function

    //This gets the query string to be added to the url
    var varString = GetQueryString();

    //Build XML string to send to the server
    var xmlString = GetXmlString();

    //Open the request using the handler name passed in and the querystring we got from the function passed in
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "../RequestHandlers/" + handlerName + ".ashx" + varString, true);
    //This tells the handler that the content of the request is XML
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    //Send the request using the XML we got from the other function passed in.
    xmlhttp.send(xmlString);
}
```

This function has a built in timeout which makes it so that if the server takes more than 30 seconds to respond to a request then any response that the client receives is ignored. For my implementations this is combined with another function that displays something to the user to tell them that the website is working on their request and if the time out elapses it tells them that a time out occurred.

The second thing this function does is it assumes that all handlers will be in a folder next to the root of your website named `RequestHandlers`. I use this set up just to consolidate all of my handler files but you can really change where it is looking to wherever you want.

The function itself takes in a string and four function pointers. The string represents the name of the handler that will be waiting to interpret the request, the four function pointers all have very specific jobs.

The first function pointer is `GetQueryString` this represents a function you will have to write that will append any variables that you deem necessary to the end of the URL being posted back to. [This site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) gives a pretty accurate explanation of what the query string should be used for. For me a common `GetQueryString` function looks something like:

```
function GetPaymentQueryString() {
    var varString = '';
    varString = "?CCPayment=True";
    return varString; 
}
```

The second function pointer, `GetXMLString`, is used to create the XML string(go figure...) that will be sent to the handler page that we are posting back to. This string will represent the bulk of the request. Everything that should not be shown to anyone snooping your requests should be sent as an XML string, if you are really paranoid you can send it as an encrypted XML string but that's not, strictly speaking, necessary. It all depends on what you are sending, if its complete credit card information then, yeah, maybe you would want to consider it, but if its first and last names then encrypting it would be overkill.

A common `GetXMLString` function might look like:

```
function GetPaymentXmlString() {
    var xmlString = '';
    xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Address><ZipCode>' + document.getElementById('txtbxZipCode').value + '</ZipCode></Address>';
    return xmlString;
}
```

The important part of that function is to get your XML right. The first tag is pretty universal and should be fine to use in most situations and then after that its all just matching the tags up. I left out a lot of your fields to save space.

The last two function pointers are what you will want to call if everything goes as planned and if something fails respectively. The way that I normally handle successful requests is to hide the inputs as a whole(usually by putting them inside of their own `div` section) and displaying a confirmation message of some sort. Failed requests can be a bit trickier because you have to tell the user why they failed. The way that I do that is by having a dummy `div` section above everything else on the page with some sort of special CSS attached to it that makes the `div` stand out in some way and if the request fails then I send a string of text from the server with my best guess of why it failed and assign it to the be displayed in the `div` section. How you decide to display the results to the user is obviously all dictated by the project itself. Since what you do when it succeeds or fails is basically on a project by project basis I can't really give a good generic example of what you should do so for this part you are on your own.

Now that we have those pieces in place, the last piece to make is the handler.

Basically for all intents and purposes a handler is basically an `ASPX` webpage with nothing on it. So the `HTML` that makes up your handler pages, which have the extension `.ashx`, will look like:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" CodeBehind="YourHandler.ashx.cs" Class="YourHandler" %>
```

And that's it. There should be no other markup in your actual `.ashx` file. Obviously the name of the handler will change depending on what you are doing.

The code behind when creating an `ashx` file by default will be a class that contains a single function named `ProcessRequest`. Basically you can treat this function as a sort of "request received" event. So in your case you would move the content of your `btnSubmit_Click` function to the `ProcessRequest` function in the `ashx` file. You can add any properties or other functions that you want but the `ProcessRequest` function must be present for the handler to work as far as I know.

One extra step that you will need to do is to get the information from the XML that was sent to your handler and also tell the response that you will be sending XML back to the client.

So to get the XML from the request you will need to do:

```
IO.StreamReader textReader = New IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream);
context.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
textReader.DiscardBufferedData();
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(textReader);
String zip = xml.Elements("Address").Elements("ZipCode").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

In order to send XML back to the client you will need to add a couple headers to the response and you accomplish that by adding(I think this is the correct way to implement an interface in C# not positive on this point though):

```
class YourHandler : System.Web.IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState
```

under your class definition and:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
context.Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(True);
```

to the beginning of your `ProcessRequest` function. Those six lines tell the client it will be receiving XML and not to cache any of the response which will ensure that your clients always see the most up-to-date content.

So. There it is. You should now have the framework to validate user input, create an AJAX request, send the request to a custom handler, accept XML from the client, write XML to the client and display the res-...I knew I forgot something...

What is the client supposed to do with the XML it gets from the server? throw it at the wall and see what sticks? No that won't work. You'll need a way to interpret the XML on the client side. Luckily the `XMLHttpRequest` object has been written to make this task a lot easier than it sounds.

You may have noticed that I set up my success and failure handlers to take a sender object and an XML object. The sender is really overkill and can be ignored(or removed) for this example to work fine. The XML object is what we are concerned with for now. Before we even get into the client side I must mention that you will have to go through the same process on the server side as you did on the client side and manually write your XML string including all the values you want the client to know about. For this example I'm going to assume you want to display a `FriendlyMessage` to the user. To write the response to the client you will do something like:

```
using (System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(context.Response.Output)) {
    context.Response.AddHeader("Success", true);
    System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Response><FriendlyMessage>" + Message + "</FriendlyMessage></Response>");
    doc.WriteTo(writer);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

On the client side to get the `FriendlyMessage` from the XML you will need to do:

```
xml.getElementsByTagName("FriendlyMessage")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Now this line makes a few assumptions. Like, you may want to add some checks in to make sure `xml.getElementsByTagName("FriendlyMessage")` actually has children before trying to evaluate them. Those sorts of checks are up to your discretion.

This time I think I've actually covered all the steps. I hope my "little" guide helps you and I didn't bore you too much. I apologize for the length but its sort of a process so getting it right takes a few steps. Once you get the base line in place and working it really lends itself to any situation. This layout also makes your user experience much better than having them wait for full trips to the server each time.

I sincerely hope this helps you get your project done and that I haven't skipped a step or something equally as embarrassing...

Comment: Thank you very much for help! I need to learn it. As I understood you used VB? As I use C#. So I need first convert server code to C#.

Comment: ahh I'm more comfortable with VB.NET. I've converted the code but since I'm not as familiar with C# I may have made a mistake.